# deploy asp.net core con kestrel y apache (proxy inverso)

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, centos7, kestrel

tengo un web api, que esta hecho en .net core, el cual ejecuto en una maquina con centos 7 desde un servidor kestrel sin problemas. (dotnet run). Modifique el archivo Program.cs para que publicara en un puerto diferente al 5000
.UseUrls("http://localhost:3083")

Mi problema, es que estoy necesitando pasar esta app a producción (en una intranet sin acceso a internet), y para ello, instale apache en el server, y genere un proxy inverso (active correctamente los módulos) que apuntara a donde tengo el servidor kestrel funcionando (puerto 3083)

A pesar que puedo consultar la api directamente desde el kestrel con http://localhost:83/api/comunas
(por ejemplo) desde el proxy inverso no puedo acceder.
mi configuración en el proxy inverso es:

```html
<VirtualHost *:83>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3083/
ProxyPassReserve / http://0.0.0.0:3083/
</VirtualHost>
```

Alguien mas ha tratado de implementar esta forma de hostear una app .net así?.
Saludos y gracias por leer.